# What is the best way to implement a FIFO collection in mongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, database-design, mongodb-query

I have a sorted time series of items. Every 1 second I want to insert a document that contains an arbitrary count:

`{ count: Number }`

Then every 5 seconds I want to remove the first documents that were inserted until the cumulative sum of the count in those documents is greater than 10.

So I have a list (collection) like this:

`[{ count: 5 }, { count: 3 }, { count: 2 }, { count: 7 }, { count: 8 }]`

Then after removing the first documents it becomes

`[{ count: 7 }, { count: 8 }]`

because `5 + 3 + 2 == 10` I stop removing documents.

The list is guaranteed to be sorted so that only elements from the beginning of the list will be removed and elements will only be appended to the end.

What is the best way to implement a FIFO list like this so that removing elements is O(1) and appending elements is also O(1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a timestamp field to each document, write the current time into it, when querying sort by the timestamp.

Alternatively you could use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) and [$pop](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/) to implement a queue in a single document.

Comment: This isn't efficient though. It does a full sort on the documents each time i want to remove  instead of just an O(1) removal.

Comment: Documents in a collection are not ordered.

Comment: MongoDB is a general purpose data store. If you want a high-performance queue, there is other software which does that function better such as Redis. It is my impression that Redis does not provide  durability guarantees that MongoDB provides, to name one difference between the two.

Comment: Can you edit and add this to your answer? Then I'll accept it as the accepted answer.